# my python innterpreter works weird 5*5 = 28

Tags: python

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUOcG.png
the full code is here:

```py
for number in range(100, 1000):
    value = number
    hundreds = number / 100
    number %= 100
    tens = number / 10
    digits = number % 10
    # print("%d = %d%d%d" % (value, hundreds, tens, digits))
    if value == 153:
        print("here is %d,  %d-%d-%d, %d" % (value, hundreds, tens, digits, tens*tens))
        if value == (hundreds ** 3 + tens ** 3 + digits ** 3):
            print("satisfied")
            print(value)
```

Comment: `tens` is 5.3. `%d` truncates it to an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tens` is 5.3. When you print with `%d`, it is truncated to an integer; that's why it shows as 5.

For int division in Python 3, you need `//` instead of `/`.